# order by case and alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

How can I use

```
ORDER BY 
CASE @AccountOperator
WHEN '>' THEN AccountTrxValue 
END ASC,
CASE @AccountOperator
WHEN '<' THEN AccountTrxValue 
END DESC
```

when AccountTrxValue is an alias and a result of the following in the "select"?

```
CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
    PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
    ELSE PAA.EarnValue END
    AS AccountTrxValue ,
```

It dosesn't accept the alias because of the case

(without using sub query)

### EDIT:

so someone answered me and I did it that way:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN @AccountOperator IS NULL OR @AccountOperator IN ('>','=') THEN
        CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
        PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
        ELSE PAA.EarnValue  END 
    END DESC,  
CASE 
    WHEN @AccountOperator = '<'THEN
        CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
        PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
        ELSE PAA.EarnValue  END 
    END
```

How can I write it in a shorter way?
*I couldn't include the null in the "in"
* I had to do 2 cases because it seems that "desc" should be written after the "end"

Comment: Please re-tag with something a little more specific than "orderby"

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @AccountOperator
        WHEN '>' THEN AccountTrxValue 
        WHEN '<' THEN -AccountTrxValue
    END
```

You should be allowed to use column aliases in the ORDER BY clause, assuming SQL Server

Otherwise:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @AccountOperator
        WHEN '>' THEN
        CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
        PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
        ELSE PAA.EarnValue END
    WHEN '<' THEN
        -CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
        PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
        ELSE PAA.EarnValue END
END
```

Edit:

The -AccountTrxValue or -CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0... simply negates the value. This means the default ASC works like a DESC...

Edit2:
General case for non-numerics

```
DECLARE @Switch char(1);
SELECT @Switch = '<';

SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol ASC) AS SortASC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol DESC) AS SortDESC
FROM
    dbo.tablename
ORDER BY 
    CASE @Switch
        WHEN '<' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol ASC)
        WHEN '>' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol DESC)
        ELSE 0
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks
What is the -AccountTrxValue?I see sql server doesn't accep it
the alias is not accepted because of the case

Comment: I entered the  CASE WHEN PAA.RedeemValue>0 THEN
        PAA.RedeemValue * -1 
        ELSE PAA.EarnValue END
insted of the alias and it worked-thanks!
can you try to answer my edits for the question?

Comment: Done. Remember the great big tick next to my answer ;-)

Comment: What would you do if the column to sort by was nvarchar or datetime?

Comment: [You can't use column aliases in an expression in an `order by`. It is only valid to use these bare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662780/sorting-nulls-last/12664195#12664195)